# Class not removing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (){

            var postcode = $('#postcode-form').val();

            function errors(){
                if(postcode == ""){
                    $('#postcode-form').addClass("form-error");
                }else{
                    $('#postcode-form').removeClass("form-error");
                }
            }

            $('#submit-form').click(errors);
        });
```

The class adds when the form is empty but doesn't remove when I enter details in the form. I don't understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the postcode chunk of code within your function. Otherwise it gets the value only once when the page loads. By placing it within the function, it'll check the value on each click.

```
function errors() {
    var postcode = $('#postcode-form').val();
    if (postcode == "") {
        $('#postcode-form').addClass("form-error");
    } else {
        $('#postcode-form').removeClass("form-error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So now you know why it isn't working.  I would take advantage of the blunder though, and refactor to cache the selector!

```
$(document).ready(function (){

        var $postcode = $('#postcode-form');

        function errors(){
            if($postcode.val() == ""){
                $postcode.addClass("form-error");
            }else{
                $postcode.removeClass("form-error");
            }
        }

        $('#submit-form').click(errors);
    });
```